# How can I adjust nested if statements in the algpseudocode package

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode, algpseudocode

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Main D Algorithm}\label{alg:cap}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\For{a for statement}
\If{some coding}
    \State do something
\ElsIf{another condition}
    \For{some condition}
    \If{another statement}
    \State do something
\ElsIf{problem is here}
\State whatever
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

It is showing like this:

[image: output]

My problem is that I want the last elseif  statement (line 8) to align with my first if statement (line 2), I am not able to do this. I tried things like using endif (obviously I modified my \usepackage then) but the algorithm didn't adjust
Any help on how to adjust this and indentations in general in this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to close all `\For` loops and `\If` statements by `\EndFor` and `\EndIf`, respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Main D Algorithm}\label{alg:cap}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\For{a for statement}
    \If{some coding}
        \State do something
    \ElsIf{another condition}
        \For{some condition}
            \If{another statement}
                \State do something
            \EndIf
        \EndFor
    \ElsIf{problem is here}
        \State whatever
    \EndIf
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```